# Fetch data using JPA and write in txt file, using java

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I need to fetch around 5 million rows from database and write it to txt file. I am planning to write data in chunks. Also need to process one column. In my case, Is it better to use JDBC then hibernate, If yes, why?

Comment: batch in background process

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you are reading from one table that closely matches your output, and odds are there will be no changes after this is done, the simplicity of JDBC might be appreciated (even if it has a clunky API).

If you need to modify your solution a few times the flexibility of JPA might be appreciated.

In short, it's hard to know the answer without looking at a possible solution first; and, even then, some of the "right" answer will be based on the opinion of the person judging it to be "right" or "wrong."

Comment: I have 3 inner joins in the query. In that case, should I go for JPA or JDBC?

Comment: @Glory Again, it's a matter of opinion.  If you don't have an opinion, use the tool you're more familiar with.

Comment: After investigating, I have planned to use JPA with "setFirstResult(offset)" and     "setMaxResults(pageLimit)". I will use an ArrayList to populate the resultSet. Do you know how can I free memory for that ArrayList, after using it.